# Sanitize and standardize street addresses using Google Maps lookups

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, pandas, google-maps

Take in incomplete user input street addresses, clean it, segregate based on word count and run it into Google maps places api and output completed & standardised addresses based on Json object retrieved.

Looking for specific input on:

1. Does this code work fine at your end (as it works at mine)- i.e., does it do what it should? (it works fine at my end but I'm apprehensive)
2. Can it be made more efficient in terms of space, time & computing required?
3. Are there alternate ways to handle this task (street address classification, auto-completion and standardisation)?

FYI, I coded this on my Jupyter Notebook, where it works as intended.

```
# coding: utf-8

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import googlemaps

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='AIzaSyDNF4JxWbuqnYNik2Np4XIpfAU8eOaY0Fg')

data = pd.read_csv('test_address_(clean).txt')
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
data.set_index(['ID'],inplace=True)
data.head()

#CLEAN THIS DATA
#REPLACE . WITH ,
#COMMA FOLLOWED BY 1 SPACE AND PRECEDED BY NON
#REMOVE DOUBLE SPACE

def subDot(Str):
    return re.sub("[.]",", ",Str)

data['Address']=data['Address'].apply(subDot)

data.head()

data['Address'] = data['Address'].str.strip()
data['Address'] = data['Address'].str.replace(' ,',', ')
data['Address'] = data['Address'].str.replace(',',', ')
data['Address'] = data['Address'].str.replace(' ',' ')

data.head() #clean data

#check word count for guiding our segmentation
data['wordcount']=data['Address'].str.split(" ").apply(len)
data.head()


#Check unresolvable addresses

unresolvable_address=data[data['Resolvable']==0]

unresolvable_address.info()

unresolvable_address.head(20)

#we see that most of these addresses are 1 or 2 words long
#lets see how many data points in total are too short
data[data['wordcount']<3].info()

data[data['wordcount']<2].info()

data[data['wordcount']<3]['Resolvable'].sum()


data[data['wordcount']<2]['Resolvable'].sum()

#Ok there are 44 data points of 1 or 2 words in length, with 28 of them resolvable and 16 not.
#And there are 21 data points of 1 word length, with 10 of them resolvable and 11 not.
#If we include 2 word length data points, we will be introducing 15 unresolvable data points
#to minimize False Positive, It's better to not try to predict values for unresolvable data points
#So, lets not predict for these data points: 2 words or shorter

Long_address=data[data['wordcount']>2]
Long_address.info()
Long_address.head()
Long_address['Resolvable'].sum()

data['Pincode']=None
data['City']=None
data['Area']=None
data['locality']=None
data['Hnbr']=None
data['Full_Address']=None

data.head()

#Lets use our Google Maps Places API to standardize these addresses
def whereThisPlaceAtPin(Str):
    try:
        r = gmaps.geocode(Str)

        for item in r[0]["address_components"]:
            if item['types'][0] == 'postal_code':
                return item['long_name']

    except:
        return None


def whereThisPlaceAtCity(Str):
    try:
        r = gmaps.geocode(Str)

        for item in r[0]["address_components"]:
            if item['types'][0] == 'administrative_area_level_1':
                return item['long_name']

    except:
        return None


def whereThisPlaceAtArea(Str):
    try:
        r = gmaps.geocode(Str)

        for item in r[0]["address_components"]:
            if item['types'][0] == 'locality':
                return item['long_name']

    except:
        return None

def whereThisPlaceAtlocality(Str):
    try:
        r = gmaps.geocode(Str)

        for item in r[0]["address_components"]:
            if item['types'][0] == 'political':
                return item['long_name']

    except:
        return None

def whereThisPlaceAtHnbr(Str):
    try:
        r = gmaps.geocode(Str)
        return r[0]["address_components"][0]['long_name']

    except:
        return None

def whereThisPlaceAtAddress(Str):
    try:
        r = gmaps.geocode(Str)
        return r[0]["formatted_address"]

    except:
        return None

data['Pincode']=data['Address'].apply(whereThisPlaceAtPin)

data['City']=data['Address'].apply(whereThisPlaceAtCity)

data['Area']=data['Address'].apply(whereThisPlaceAtArea)

data['locality']=data['Address'].apply(whereThisPlaceAtlocality)

data['Hnbr']=data['Address'].apply(whereThisPlaceAtHnbr)

data['Full_Address']=data['Address'].apply(whereThisPlaceAtAddress)

data.head()

data[data['wordcount']>2].loc['Pincode'] = None

data[data['wordcount']>2].loc['City'] = None

data.to_csv("Checkpoint_final.csv")
```